# Pivoting a table by week with start and end date columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I have data that looks something like this.

| ticket_id | group | date_opened | date_closed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sales | 2021-01-03 | 2021-05-02 |
| 2 | sales | 2022-09-12 | NULL |
| 3 | HR | 2013-05-05 | NULL |
| 4 | HR | 2023-05-05 | 2023-05-07 |

What I want is a pivot table that summarizes how many open tickets each group had per week. Not -- and this is crucial -- not how many were *created*, but how many tickets were *open at some point* during that week. Basically, do the two date ranges overlap at all.

So something like this. Not all groups will have tickets open during each week.

| group | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-08 | 2023-01-15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sales | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| HR | 0 | 10 | 18 |
| eng | 500 | 300 | 100 |

My problem is (1) I suck at pivot tables and (2) I have no idea how to deal with date range overlap in SQL. I'm open to not pivot tables, too, but I think that's what I want?

If it matters, this is being done in Snowflake.

As a first step, I tried to generate it for a single hard-coded week, and I think this works:

```
SELECT 
   group,
   COUNT_IF(
      date_opened <= DATEADD(week, 1, '2023-05-07') AND 
      (date_closed >= '2023-05-07' OR date_closed IS NULL))) as "2023-05-07"
FROM tickets
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Snowflake doesn't seem to have a date range generator. I did find this snippet that will generate weeks from a starting date.

```
SELECT 
   DATEADD(week, '+' || SEQ4(), '2023-01-01'::DATE) as dte 
from table 
  (generator(rowcount => WEEKOFYEAR(current_date())));
```

I can join this to the other table, but...what am I joining on? Neither of the dates in the other table have to be contained in this week.

Comment: is something "open" until a date_closed is provided?

Comment: Yep, that's correct! date_closed can be null, which means it's still open.

Answer (score 0):

I am not answering the pivot aspect of your question, just how do you generate the date series and ythen join that to your data. Note the following is in Postgres but I believe the recursive CTE syntax is similar in Snowflake but there may be some differences in how to create the inital date or how to add 7 days.

```
WITH RECURSIVE dates
AS (
    SELECT DATE ('2023-04-01') AS dte
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT (dte + 7)
    FROM dates
    WHERE dte < CURRENT_DATE
    )

    SELECT
         grp
        , dte
        , TO_CHAR(dte, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS dte_label
        , COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tickets t
    JOIN dates d ON d.dte >= t.date_opened AND d.dte < COALESCE(date_closed, CURRENT_DATE) 
                 OR d.dte + 6 >= t.date_opened AND d.dte + 6 < COALESCE(date_closed, CURRENT_DATE)
    GROUP BY
          grp
        , dte
```

So the join assesses if the generated dates fall into the date range formed by `date_opened` either to `date_closed` or the current date if date_closed is null. Then you get a row structure like this:

| grp | dte | dte_label | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HR | 2023-05-20 | 2023-05-20 | 1 |
| HR | 2023-04-29 | 2023-04-29 | 2 |
| sales | 2023-05-06 | 2023-05-06 | 1 |
| HR | 2023-06-03 | 2023-06-03 | 1 |
| HR | 2023-05-06 | 2023-05-06 | 2 |
| sales | 2023-05-20 | 2023-05-20 | 1 |
| sales | 2023-04-08 | 2023-04-08 | 1 |
| sales | 2023-06-03 | 2023-06-03 | 1 |
| HR | 2023-05-13 | 2023-05-13 | 1 |
| HR | 2023-05-27 | 2023-05-27 | 1 |
| sales | 2023-04-22 | 2023-04-22 | 1 |
| sales | 2023-04-29 | 2023-04-29 | 1 |
| sales | 2023-05-27 | 2023-05-27 | 1 |
| sales | 2023-04-15 | 2023-04-15 | 1 |
| sales | 2023-05-13 | 2023-05-13 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uilql6wq)

Comment: Btw: it should not matter how you generate the date series, the method you propose should also work. A recursive cte is just an alternative technique.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do a pivot is do a group by the “group” column on a particular date. Then as you have other dates join those results using the group names.